# Datasnap - insert record with parameter

Tags: delphi, datasnap

On DatasnapServer I have :
TSQLConnection connected to my database.
SQLDataset1 (CommandType=ctQuery) that fetches data from my table (lets call it "RESORTS".
DataSetProvider1 is connected to my SQLDataset1.
DataSetProvider1 is set to AllowCommandText.

This works OK. Server starts without a problem. Data is obtained.

On the Client side I have :
SQLConnection1 which is connected OK.Driver is Datasnap.
DSProviderConnection1 is linked to my  SQLConnection1.
Both connected without problem.
Then I have DataSource1 which is connected to a ClientDataSet1.
ClientDataSet1 is connected to my DataSetProvider1.
Setting it active retrieves the data from the server.
All displayed right in the grid.

On the Client form I have a Edit1 and a Button1.
I try and run a query using the ClientDataset1

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ClientDataSet1.Close;
ClientDataSet1.CommandText := ' INSERT INTO RESORTS (RES_NAME) VALUES (:RN)';
ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('RN').AsString := Edit1.Text;
ClientDataSet1.Execute;
ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
```

I get : ClientDataSet1: Field 'RN' not found.

So, I am wondering what is going on? Why cant I insert data with parameter?
If I substitute the parameter with : 
ClientDataSet1.CommandText := ' INSERT INTO RESORTS (RES_NAME) VALUES ("TRY")';
I get :Remote error: SQLDataSet1: Cursor not returned from Query. 
However, the data does get inserted.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Press F1 on 'CommandText' of 'ClientDataSet' and read, it is trying to retrieve data, hence *"Cursor not returned.."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Rewritten based on new information provided by the poster in comments.)

Your entire approach is wrong. :-) You don't use parameters, SQL or `CommandText`. The [TClientDataSet.CommandText documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet.CommandText) clearly says:

> CommandText specifies what data the client dataset wants to receive from its (internal or external) provider. It is either:
>
> - An SQL statement (query) for the database server to execute.
> - The name of a table or stored procedure

An SQL statement (query) means only a `SELECT` is acceptable SQL. An `INSERT` is not a query, so it cannot be used in a `CommandText` to insert data.

To insert data in a `TClientDataSet`, you simply `Insert` or `Append`, and then use `FieldByName` to set the value, and then call the `Post` method:

```
ClientDataSet1.Insert;
ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('RES_NAME').AsString := Edit1.Text;
ClientDataSet1.Post;
```

To edit, you simply use `Edit` instead of `Insert` or `Append`; the rest stays exactly the same.

```
ClientDataSet1.Edit;
ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('RES_NAME').AsString := Edit1.Text;
ClientDataSet1.Post;
```

When you're ready to actually update the server data from the changes made in the `TClientDataSet`, call it's `ApplyUpdates`:

```
ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0);
```

Comment: ClientDataSet1.Params.ParamByName('RN').AsString := Edit1.Text; gives me 'cursor not returned from query' error and the data gets inserted twice !

Comment: It works fine for me, but I have no idea what you're doing with the open ClientDataSet1 after the code you've shown is finished. You typically set the SQL, assign a parameter value, execute the query, and then close it immediately; there's no accessible content after an INSERT statement executes. (It's not 'Params.ParamByName' if your code refers to TSQLDataSet; it's just `ParamByName`, as my code says.) Hang on - I see the issue. I just copied your code. Change the `Execute` to `ExecSQL`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It seems you must write 'params' first. Otherwise : [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(131): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ParamByName'.ClientDataSet1 I use to get data in the grid, so I must close it first to execute the query with it. Even if I remove the opening and closing of the dataset i still get the same errors.

Comment: If you have to write `Params.ParamByName`, then you're not using a TSQLDataSet as you said you were. Regardless, the error is because you cannot retrieve data from a query after doing an INSERT, because there is none. You need to do another SELECT to get the data to display in the grid.

Comment: If I use a separate TSQLDataSet and run the query, I get Remote error : dbxSql is an unrecognised command type

Comment: You've gone off in a totally separate direction from what was asked in your question, which was how to insert a record with parameters. I've answered that question. I can't diagnose or debug other code of yours that I can't see.

Comment: Brilliant ! However, I cant use ExecSQL because ClientdataSet has no such property.

Comment: It would be great if you would be consistent. First you say you're using TSQLDataSet, which has both ParamByName (with needing to use Params first) and ExecSQL. (I verified that first before posting.) Now you're referring to it requiring Params.ParamByName and not having ExecSQL, which means you're using something else entirely. (A standard TClientDataSet does not have a CommandText property, does not support SQL.) It helps if you provide specifics about what components you're actually using, so we know what we're trying to answer. What specific class is your ClientDataSet1?

Comment: Thank you Ken ! I did not stray from the question however, its just that I was trying to figure out what was going on.Never used this datasnap before....

Comment: I'm really confused. If you're using a TSQLDataSet or TClientDataSet, you're going about it all wrong anyway; you don't need CommandText, Parameters, or Execute/ExecSQL. You simply call `TClientDataSet.Insert`, use `FieldByName('RES_NAME`).AsString := Edit1.Text;`, and then call the `TClientDataSet.Post` method. There's absolutely no SQL required. Can you clarify **exactly** what class type your `ClientDataSet1` is?

Comment: OK. I'm going to change my entire answer. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: I have tried the other option you mentioned too (without the need of SQL). However I hav run into a problem where the insert requires the value of autoinc(?) firld from that table. Theres 2 fields : R_ID (autoinc) and RES_NAME (string). When I try a simple insert like you suggested,I trigger R_ID must have a value. Why it needs a value which is supposed to be autoinc anyway,beats me....

Comment: Because the clientdataset has no ability to autoinc fields; it's an in-memory dataset that is not connected to the server. It fetches the data when you open it from the server, and has no more contact with the server until you call ApplyUpdates. Where would it get the autoinc value from?

Comment: sql does not produce that error. So basically,if i understand you correctly, I cant use insert example like the one you suggested ?

Comment: No. TClientDataSet does not use SQL at all, except for the SELECT you can provide in the CommandText. See the help file for TClientDataSet.CommandText, which tells you it only accepts a query (which is a SELECT statement) or the name of a table or stored procedure. You cannot use an INSERT statement as your code attempts using a TClientDataSet. Assign a valie to the autoinc field, and let the server deal with updating them. If need be, you can use the TClientDataSet.OnReconcileError event to sort things out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClientDataSet1.ParamByName('RN').AsString := Edit1.Text;`

Comment: No, you can't. (We've been through that above.) TClientDataSet won't allow an INSERT in it's CommandText, therefore there's no parameter to assign to with ParamByName. The proper way is in my answer.